# The meaning of s(size) in Matplotlib's scatter()

Tags: python, matplotlib

The `scatter` function used to paint different data points that are actually full circles.

They can be of different sizes. The s parameter (to `ax.scatter`) contains the sizes of data points.

Form the documentation of Matplotlib:

> The marker size in points**2 (typographic points are 1/72 in.).
> Default is rcParams['lines.markersize'] ** 2.

To check distance between to points, I converted them to inches and then used:

```
 if (math.sqrt(allsizes[i]/3.14) + math.sqrt(allsizes[j])/3.14) > distance/72:
     print('overlap')
```

For some reason it almost works, but in cases of small overlap, it fails to find it. When it says there is overlap, there is overlap.

I am not sure if the sizes are `R^2` or `pi*R^2`, but none of these options seems to work.
What did I do wrong?

Adding calculation:

```
def calc_distance(ax, x, y):
        diffy = abs(y[i] - y[j])
        diffx = abs(matplotlib.dates.date2num(x[i]) - matplotlib.dates.date2num(x[j]))
        origin = ax.figure.dpi_scale_trans.transform((0, 0))
        vec = ax.figure.dpi_scale_trans.transform((diffx, diffy))
        vec = np.array(vec) - np.array(origin)
        distance = np.linalg.norm(vec, ord=2)  # Distance on display node
        return distance
```